# How to fix an error when using sapply with sequence function

Tags: r, sapply, seq

I was trying to use sapply with sequence function, but it keeps giving me an error message, and I don't know how to fix it. Here is an example code that I try to solve

```
a <-  data.frame(var = seq(1, 10, by = 0.5))
i  <- seq(1,5, by = 1)

results <- sapply(i, function(x) seq(min(a$var), max(a$var), by = i))
```

and it keeps giving me an error message as below.

```
Error in seq.default(min(a$var), max(a$var), by = i) : 
  'by' must be of length 1
```

although there is the error message regarding the code, I still don't understand the cause of the problem. I'd appreciate if someone could help me to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need  `by = x`.

Comment: @RonakShah It worked! Since I am not familiar with apply function yet, I could not think of it. Thank you!